# Logback log to multiple files with a common module

Tags: java, logback

I know that it is possible to log to multiple files based on a package. My question is slightly different. Given the following packaging:

```
 - foo.bar.moduleA
 - foo.bar.moduleB
 - foo.bar.commonModule
```

In this scenario, moduleA and moduleB have code that is called from the commonModule. The problem I have is that I get two log files that only contain logging from moduleA or only logging from moduleB. I know this is because of the package level logging I am using but I don't know how to expand it to say log everything from this package and any other packages that are called later on in this thread. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html), but you'll need to instrument your code, when your start your moduleA or moduleB thread so that it put something in the MDC:

```
MDC.put("module", "moduleA"); // or B
```

You can then put `%X{module}` to your pattern and filter thing using grep/whatever, or you can use [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/sift/SiftingAppender.html) and [MDCBasedDiscriminator](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/sift/MDCBasedDiscriminator.html). There is an example [in this page](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html).